# Liferay: Can't find the plugins installed and project validation in preferences using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ide, liferay, liferay-ide

i want to add plugins to my ide, but eclipse doesn't give me the " plugins installed" and " project validation" in preferences window.
[in the selection there is no "plugins installed" and "project validation"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRQ4e.png)

Comment: I have no clue what you're asking about. Please clarify what you've done, what you see and what you expect to see.

Comment: i posted a screen shot , you can see it when you click down on the link "in the selection there is no "plugins installed" and "project validation" " .

Comment: i've just started working with liferay, and i want to use the eclipse ide. I downloaded eclipse from here https://www.liferay.com/fr/downloads/liferay-portal/available-releases  . and i added tomcat 7 as a server. but i can't add pluggins

Comment: I've seen that. That's obviously what you see. I don't know what you expect to see and what you want to do with it. Also I don't know which version of the IDE you're running...

Comment: when i try to create a new liferay portelet an error message appears " there is no plugin selected'

Comment: i am following the steps of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCdmNb10kzc

Comment: do you have any idea about this probleme please?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details - e.g. detailed steps to reproduce. The video that you link is for Liferay 6.1, thus it's quite aged. And please don't expect us to go through a 12 minute video - instead you should do the work of summarizing what you actually did. If you want to go for more current material, you might want to start with projects from https://dev.liferay.com on the current versions

Answer (score 0):

try following step for liferay plugins in eclipse,

1) go in to the help menu and select the "Eclipse Marketplace"

2) then pop up window appear , type liferay in the search box and press search button and then select first one as shown in screenshot.[liferay plugins for eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30DYn.png)

install this .
thats it for plugins .

Comment: oups! it's alreay installed, i need to install plugins to liferay not to eclipse